# When to use object.recycle() in java?

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android development and have a basic knowledge of Java. Often I see `.recycle()` being used in different codes. Reading a few documents I learnt that the method is mostly used to recycle *Bitmaps* to save memory avoid exceptions like `OutOfMemoryError` (However, their may be an alternative on Android Version 3.0 and higher, I saw somewhere).

However, recently I was reading a [tutorial](http://www.jayway.com/2012/06/25/creating-custom-android-views-part-1-extending-standard-views-and-adding-new-xml-attributes/) about custom views and came to know that the method `recycle()` is also used with `TypedArray`; which left me wondering about other possible uses of the method. 
My questions are:

1. What are the other areas where recycle should be used?
2. Should recycle method even be used with objects of a user created class if they grow complex?

I may be entirely wrong about the concepts above, if so can someone please point me to the right direction with proper links to articles like 'when to use recycle() and why?', thanks.

Comment: `Object`s have [no `recycle` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).